# How to split a text line, and use one part as file name and the other part as file content

Tags: bash

I have a large text file `large.txt` that contains lines in the form of of

```
// dbname.filename.json[{"some":"very long", "...":"...", "JSON":"string"}]

// dbname.other_filename.json[{"sdfs":"dfdv", "...":"...", "osifu":"cvvcb"}]

// dbname.yet_another_filename.json[{"vcv":"t54tr", "...":"...", "yugf":"hft"}]
```

I'd like to use Bash to split up the large file into JSON files, each with the file name at the beginning of the line. That would be `filename.json` in the above example. I only got up to here

```
grep '^\/\/ dbname\.' large.txt | sed -r 's#// dbname\.##'
```

Is there a way to split a text line, and use one part as file name and the other part as file content?

The result would be, for example

- file `filename.json` only containing the string `[{"some":"very long", "...":"...", "JSON":"string"}]`
- file `other_filename.json` only ontaining the string `[{"sdfs":"dfdv", "...":"...", "osifu":"cvvcb"}]`
- etc.

Comment: Should `[{"some":"very long", "...":"...", "JSON":"string"}]` be stored in `filenames.json`? Is JSON data always in single and same line ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. Each line consists of the `// dbname.filename.json` immediately followed by a string of JSON data, all in one line. The resulting files should contain that JSON string and should be named according to the file name at the beginning of the line.

Comment: Added some more detail to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending over your pipeline, we get:

```
grep '^\/\/\s*dbname\.' large.txt | sed -r 's#//\s*dbname\.##;s/\[/>[/1' | awk -F '>' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i >> $1}'
```

Output:

```
$ cat large.txt 
// dbname.filename.json[{"some":"very long", "...":"...", "JSON":"string"}]

// dbname.other_filename.json[{"sdfs":"dfdv", "...":"...", "osifu":"cvvcb"}]

// dbname.yet_another_filename.json[{"vcv":"t54tr", "...":"...", "yugf":"hft"}]
$ ls
large.txt
$ grep '^\/\/\s*dbname\.' large.txt | sed -r 's#//\s*dbname\.##;s/\[/>[/1' | awk -F '>' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i >> $1}'
$ ls
filename.json  large.txt  other_filename.json  yet_another_filename.json
$ cat filename.json 
[{"some":"very long", "...":"...", "JSON":"string"}]
$ cat other_filename.json 
[{"sdfs":"dfdv", "...":"...", "osifu":"cvvcb"}]
$ cat yet_another_filename.json 
[{"vcv":"t54tr", "...":"...", "yugf":"hft"}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one detail, the result strings are missing the `[ ]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -F'[' '{sub(/^\/\/\s*dbname\./,"",$0); f=$1; $1=FS; print $0 > f }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple awk command with custom field separator:

```
awk -F '\\.json' 'NF==2{sub(/.*\./, "", $1); print $2 > $1 ".json"}' file
```

With your sample data it will create 3 `.json` files:

```
yet_another_filename.json
other_filename.json
filename.json
```